question about Argand's Diagram
In this link: http://www.maeckes.nl/Arganddiagram%20FR.html, there is an image of the Argand Diagram.

On the imaginary axis, the author labels the points, $b$ (representing the imaginary part of $z$), and $-b$ (representing the imaginary part of the complex conjugate of $z$). This labeling aligns with my knowledge.
However, I am a little confused as to why the author labels $i$ and $-i$ as well. Shouldn't it be $1$ and $-1$ instead?

I'm afraid that this is simply a custom to write it like that. As already pointed out in the answers, for the sake of consistency, it should be labelled differently, but rarely not even mathematics is safe from tradition beating common sense.

You are correct from a logical standpoint. I suspect the author was afraid that would be too confusing. Ideally, the diagram would have $ib$ and $-ib$ instead of $b$ and $-b$.
Note that $i$and$-i$ are in a different color and on the other side of the axis.
Is it possible the accompanying text explains the diagram?

Thanks. I speak French, and the accompanying text doesn't add any information. By the way, if the labeling was $ib$ and $-ib$ instead, shouldn't the imaginary axis be labeled $iIm$?

I think Im makes sense as just being short for “imaginary”, i.e., the imaginary axis, and not the imaginary part of a complex number. In a way, you’re overthinking things. You’re right. But the author must have felt that more readers would have been confused if he stuck to the logically correct labeling. Or maybe your points just didn’t occur to him.

Yes, you're right. The author has already mentioned the  Imaginary axis, so, after that the author can refrain from writing $i$. Instead, the author can just write 1, 2, etc, which represent the magnitude of the imaginary part of the complex number.
Especially if the author has written $b$ at the axis as well.
The other thing the author could've done is to not mention the imaginary axis, in which case he could've written $i$, $ib$, or $-ib$, etc.
